# animate padding of parent only

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, menu

I have a header with a dropdown menu, now I want to edit the padding of the header when you scroll, but I DONT want to change the padding of the dropdown menu...
HTML:

```
<li><a>Menu</a>
<ul>
    <li><a>Dropdown</a></li>
    <li><a>Dropdown</a></li>
    <li><a>Dropdown</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".navigator li").animate({ paddingTop : '15px', paddingBottom : '15px' }, {duration: 200, queue:false});
```

Now how can I keep the padding of the children at 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `.navigator` is the class of your parent `<ul>` element, you can use the [direct descendent selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) (`>`):

```
$(".navigator > li").animate({ paddingTop : '15px', paddingBottom : '15px' }, {duration: 200, queue:false});
```